# I coudn't hibernate my Windows 7 system (Dell XPS laptop)

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, dell-xps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernation does not work, I’m always returned to the sign in screen](https://superuser.com/questions/485776/hibernation-does-not-work-im-always-returned-to-the-sign-in-screen)

I've enabled hibernation in the power settings and the hibernate button is available in the start menu. But when I click on that the screen is fading out and it's going back to the login screen. It's not hibernating.

About my laptop:

OS - Windows 7 SP 1 Processor - Intel Core i7.

Last thing I did: Earlier when I got the system with pre-installed windows, it was working. But formatted the system and installed Fedora 17 and Windows 7. After that it's not working.